# How do I do a contour integral in complex analysis

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to do the integral sign over the sign gamma (integrating around a path gamma)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do you mean like this ?

```
\oint\limits_{Gamma}x\,\mathrm{d}\gamma
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to insert a thinspace, `\,`, between `x` and `\mathrm{d}`.